# can't set SPI mode: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: linux, arm, spi

I compiled the `spidev_test` tool using `spidev_test.c` in Linux kernel v6.4.0, and I used this tool to execute it on my device. When using

```sh
spidev_test -D /dev/spidev1.0
```

the following error was reported.

```sh
can't set spi mode: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Aborted
```

My device is a customized Linux system with an ARM processor.

```sh
# ls /dev/spidev1.0
/dev/spidev1.0
```

---

`spidev_test.c`:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-only
/*
 * SPI testing utility (using spidev driver)
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2007  MontaVista Software, Inc.
 * Copyright (c) 2007  Anton Vorontsov <avorontsov@ru.mvista.com>
 *
 * Cross-compile with cross-gcc -I/path/to/cross-kernel/include
 */

#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
//#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
#include "spidev.h"

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))

static void pabort(const char *s)
{
    if (errno != 0)
        perror(s);
    else
        printf("%s\n", s);

    abort();
}

static const char *device = "/dev/spidev1.1";
static uint32_t mode;
static uint8_t bits = 8;
static char *input_file;
static char *output_file;
static uint32_t speed = 500000;
static uint16_t delay;
static int verbose;
static int transfer_size;
static int iterations;
static int interval = 5; /* interval in seconds for showing transfer rate */

static uint8_t default_tx[] = {
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x95,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0xF0, 0x0D,
};

static uint8_t default_rx[ARRAY_SIZE(default_tx)] = {0, };
static char *input_tx;

static void hex_dump(const void *src, size_t length, size_t line_size,
             char *prefix)
{
    int i = 0;
    const unsigned char *address = src;
    const unsigned char *line = address;
    unsigned char c;

    printf("%s | ", prefix);
    while (length-- > 0) {
        printf("%02X ", *address++);
        if (!(++i % line_size) || (length == 0 && i % line_size)) {
            if (length == 0) {
                while (i++ % line_size)
                    printf("__ ");
            }
            printf(" |");
            while (line < address) {
                c = *line++;
                printf("%c", (c < 32 || c > 126) ? '.' : c);
            }
            printf("|\n");
            if (length > 0)
                printf("%s | ", prefix);
        }
    }
}

/*
 *  Unescape - process hexadecimal escape character
 *      converts shell input "\x23" -> 0x23
 */
static int unescape(char *_dst, char *_src, size_t len)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int match;
    char *src = _src;
    char *dst = _dst;
    unsigned int ch;

    while (*src) {
        if (*src == '\\' && *(src+1) == 'x') {
            match = sscanf(src + 2, "%2x", &ch);
            if (!match)
                pabort("malformed input string");

            src += 4;
            *dst++ = (unsigned char)ch;
        } else {
            *dst++ = *src++;
        }
        ret++;
    }
    return ret;
}

static void transfer(int fd, uint8_t const *tx, uint8_t const *rx, size_t len)
{
    int ret;
    int out_fd;
    struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
        .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
        .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
        .len = len,
        .delay_usecs = delay,
        .speed_hz = speed,
        .bits_per_word = bits,
    };

    if (mode & SPI_TX_OCTAL)
        tr.tx_nbits = 8;
    else if (mode & SPI_TX_QUAD)
        tr.tx_nbits = 4;
    else if (mode & SPI_TX_DUAL)
        tr.tx_nbits = 2;
    if (mode & SPI_RX_OCTAL)
        tr.rx_nbits = 8;
    else if (mode & SPI_RX_QUAD)
        tr.rx_nbits = 4;
    else if (mode & SPI_RX_DUAL)
        tr.rx_nbits = 2;
    if (!(mode & SPI_LOOP)) {
        if (mode & (SPI_TX_OCTAL | SPI_TX_QUAD | SPI_TX_DUAL))
            tr.rx_buf = 0;
        else if (mode & (SPI_RX_OCTAL | SPI_RX_QUAD | SPI_RX_DUAL))
            tr.tx_buf = 0;
    }

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
    if (ret < 1)
        pabort("can't send spi message");

    if (verbose)
        hex_dump(tx, len, 32, "TX");

    if (output_file) {
        out_fd = open(output_file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
        if (out_fd < 0)
            pabort("could not open output file");

        ret = write(out_fd, rx, len);
        if (ret != len)
            pabort("not all bytes written to output file");

        close(out_fd);
    }

    if (verbose)
        hex_dump(rx, len, 32, "RX");
}

static void print_usage(const char *prog)
{
    printf("Usage: %s [-DsbdlHOLC3vpNR24SI]\n", prog);
    puts("  -D --device   device to use (default /dev/spidev1.1)\n"
         "  -s --speed    max speed (Hz)\n"
         "  -d --delay    delay (usec)\n"
         "  -b --bpw      bits per word\n"
         "  -i --input    input data from a file (e.g. \"test.bin\")\n"
         "  -o --output   output data to a file (e.g. \"results.bin\")\n"
         "  -l --loop     loopback\n"
         "  -H --cpha     clock phase\n"
         "  -O --cpol     clock polarity\n"
         "  -L --lsb      least significant bit first\n"
         "  -C --cs-high  chip select active high\n"
         "  -3 --3wire    SI/SO signals shared\n"
         "  -v --verbose  Verbose (show tx buffer)\n"
         "  -p            Send data (e.g. \"1234\\xde\\xad\")\n"
         "  -N --no-cs    no chip select\n"
         "  -R --ready    slave pulls low to pause\n"
         "  -2 --dual     dual transfer\n"
         "  -4 --quad     quad transfer\n"
         "  -8 --octal    octal transfer\n"
         "  -S --size     transfer size\n"
         "  -I --iter     iterations\n");
    exit(1);
}

static void parse_opts(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while (1) {
        static const struct option lopts[] = {
            { "device",  1, 0, 'D' },
            { "speed",   1, 0, 's' },
            { "delay",   1, 0, 'd' },
            { "bpw",     1, 0, 'b' },
            { "input",   1, 0, 'i' },
            { "output",  1, 0, 'o' },
            { "loop",    0, 0, 'l' },
            { "cpha",    0, 0, 'H' },
            { "cpol",    0, 0, 'O' },
            { "lsb",     0, 0, 'L' },
            { "cs-high", 0, 0, 'C' },
            { "3wire",   0, 0, '3' },
            { "no-cs",   0, 0, 'N' },
            { "ready",   0, 0, 'R' },
            { "dual",    0, 0, '2' },
            { "verbose", 0, 0, 'v' },
            { "quad",    0, 0, '4' },
            { "octal",   0, 0, '8' },
            { "size",    1, 0, 'S' },
            { "iter",    1, 0, 'I' },
            { NULL, 0, 0, 0 },
        };
        int c;

        c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "D:s:d:b:i:o:lHOLC3NR248p:vS:I:",
                lopts, NULL);

        if (c == -1)
            break;

        switch (c) {
        case 'D':
            device = optarg;
            break;
        case 's':
            speed = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'd':
            delay = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'b':
            bits = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'i':
            input_file = optarg;
            break;
        case 'o':
            output_file = optarg;
            break;
        case 'l':
            mode |= SPI_LOOP;
            break;
        case 'H':
            mode |= SPI_CPHA;
            break;
        case 'O':
            mode |= SPI_CPOL;
            break;
        case 'L':
            mode |= SPI_LSB_FIRST;
            break;
        case 'C':
            mode |= SPI_CS_HIGH;
            break;
        case '3':
            mode |= SPI_3WIRE;
            break;
        case 'N':
            mode |= SPI_NO_CS;
            break;
        case 'v':
            verbose = 1;
            break;
        case 'R':
            mode |= SPI_READY;
            break;
        case 'p':
            input_tx = optarg;
            break;
        case '2':
            mode |= SPI_TX_DUAL;
            break;
        case '4':
            mode |= SPI_TX_QUAD;
            break;
        case '8':
            mode |= SPI_TX_OCTAL;
            break;
        case 'S':
            transfer_size = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'I':
            iterations = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        default:
            print_usage(argv[0]);
        }
    }
    if (mode & SPI_LOOP) {
        if (mode & SPI_TX_DUAL)
            mode |= SPI_RX_DUAL;
        if (mode & SPI_TX_QUAD)
            mode |= SPI_RX_QUAD;
        if (mode & SPI_TX_OCTAL)
            mode |= SPI_RX_OCTAL;
    }
}

static void transfer_escaped_string(int fd, char *str)
{
    size_t size = strlen(str);
    uint8_t *tx;
    uint8_t *rx;

    tx = malloc(size);
    if (!tx)
        pabort("can't allocate tx buffer");

    rx = malloc(size);
    if (!rx)
        pabort("can't allocate rx buffer");

    size = unescape((char *)tx, str, size);
    transfer(fd, tx, rx, size);
    free(rx);
    free(tx);
}

static void transfer_file(int fd, char *filename)
{
    ssize_t bytes;
    struct stat sb;
    int tx_fd;
    uint8_t *tx;
    uint8_t *rx;

    if (stat(filename, &sb) == -1)
        pabort("can't stat input file");

    tx_fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (tx_fd < 0)
        pabort("can't open input file");

    tx = malloc(sb.st_size);
    if (!tx)
        pabort("can't allocate tx buffer");

    rx = malloc(sb.st_size);
    if (!rx)
        pabort("can't allocate rx buffer");

    bytes = read(tx_fd, tx, sb.st_size);
    if (bytes != sb.st_size)
        pabort("failed to read input file");

    transfer(fd, tx, rx, sb.st_size);
    free(rx);
    free(tx);
    close(tx_fd);
}

static uint64_t _read_count;
static uint64_t _write_count;

static void show_transfer_rate(void)
{
    static uint64_t prev_read_count, prev_write_count;
    double rx_rate, tx_rate;

    rx_rate = ((_read_count - prev_read_count) * 8) / (interval*1000.0);
    tx_rate = ((_write_count - prev_write_count) * 8) / (interval*1000.0);

    printf("rate: tx %.1fkbps, rx %.1fkbps\n", rx_rate, tx_rate);

    prev_read_count = _read_count;
    prev_write_count = _write_count;
}

static void transfer_buf(int fd, int len)
{
    uint8_t *tx;
    uint8_t *rx;
    int i;

    tx = malloc(len);
    if (!tx)
        pabort("can't allocate tx buffer");
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        tx[i] = random();

    rx = malloc(len);
    if (!rx)
        pabort("can't allocate rx buffer");

    transfer(fd, tx, rx, len);

    _write_count += len;
    _read_count += len;

    if (mode & SPI_LOOP) {
        if (memcmp(tx, rx, len)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "transfer error !\n");
            hex_dump(tx, len, 32, "TX");
            hex_dump(rx, len, 32, "RX");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    free(rx);
    free(tx);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret = 0;
    int fd;
    uint32_t request;

    parse_opts(argc, argv);

    if (input_tx && input_file)
        pabort("only one of -p and --input may be selected");

    fd = open(device, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0)
        pabort("can't open device");

    /*
     * spi mode
     */
    /* WR is make a request to assign 'mode' */
    request = mode;
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE32, &mode);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set spi mode");

    /* RD is read what mode the device actually is in */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MODE32, &mode);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get spi mode");
    /* Drivers can reject some mode bits without returning an error.
     * Read the current value to identify what mode it is in, and if it
     * differs from the requested mode, warn the user.
     */
    if (request != mode)
        printf("WARNING device does not support requested mode 0x%x\n",
            request);

    /*
     * bits per word
     */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set bits per word");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get bits per word");

    /*
     * max speed hz
     */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set max speed hz");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get max speed hz");

    printf("spi mode: 0x%x\n", mode);
    printf("bits per word: %u\n", bits);
    printf("max speed: %u Hz (%u kHz)\n", speed, speed/1000);

    if (input_tx)
        transfer_escaped_string(fd, input_tx);
    else if (input_file)
        transfer_file(fd, input_file);
    else if (transfer_size) {
        struct timespec last_stat;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &last_stat);

        while (iterations-- > 0) {
            struct timespec current;

            transfer_buf(fd, transfer_size);

            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &current);
            if (current.tv_sec - last_stat.tv_sec > interval) {
                show_transfer_rate();
                last_stat = current;
            }
        }
        printf("total: tx %.1fKB, rx %.1fKB\n",
               _write_count/1024.0, _read_count/1024.0);
    } else
        transfer(fd, default_tx, default_rx, sizeof(default_tx));

    close(fd);

    return ret;
}
```

`spidev.h`:

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0+ WITH Linux-syscall-note */
/*
 * include/linux/spi/spidev.h
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2006 SWAPP
 *  Andrea Paterniani <a.paterniani@swapp-eng.it>
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 675 Mass Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139, USA.
  */

#ifndef SPIDEV_H
#define SPIDEV_H

#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
//#include <linux/spi/spi.h>
#include "spi.h"

/* IOCTL commands */

#define SPI_IOC_MAGIC           'k'

/**
 * struct spi_ioc_transfer - describes a single SPI transfer
 * @tx_buf: Holds pointer to userspace buffer with transmit data, or null.
 *  If no data is provided, zeroes are shifted out.
 * @rx_buf: Holds pointer to userspace buffer for receive data, or null.
 * @len: Length of tx and rx buffers, in bytes.
 * @speed_hz: Temporary override of the device's bitrate.
 * @bits_per_word: Temporary override of the device's wordsize.
 * @delay_usecs: If nonzero, how long to delay after the last bit transfer
 *  before optionally deselecting the device before the next transfer.
 * @cs_change: True to deselect device before starting the next transfer.
 * @word_delay_usecs: If nonzero, how long to wait between words within one
 *  transfer. This property needs explicit support in the SPI controller,
 *  otherwise it is silently ignored.
 *
 * This structure is mapped directly to the kernel spi_transfer structure;
 * the fields have the same meanings, except of course that the pointers
 * are in a different address space (and may be of different sizes in some
 * cases, such as 32-bit i386 userspace over a 64-bit x86_64 kernel).
 * Zero-initialize the structure, including currently unused fields, to
 * accommodate potential future updates.
 *
 * SPI_IOC_MESSAGE gives userspace the equivalent of kernel spi_sync().
 * Pass it an array of related transfers, they'll execute together.
 * Each transfer may be half duplex (either direction) or full duplex.
 *
 *  struct spi_ioc_transfer mesg[4];
 *  ...
 *  status = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(4), mesg);
 *
 * So for example one transfer might send a nine bit command (right aligned
 * in a 16-bit word), the next could read a block of 8-bit data before
 * terminating that command by temporarily deselecting the chip; the next
 * could send a different nine bit command (re-selecting the chip), and the
 * last transfer might write some register values.
 */
struct spi_ioc_transfer {
    __u64       tx_buf;
    __u64       rx_buf;

    __u32       len;
    __u32       speed_hz;

    __u16       delay_usecs;
    __u8        bits_per_word;
    __u8        cs_change;
    __u8        tx_nbits;
    __u8        rx_nbits;
    __u8        word_delay_usecs;
    __u8        pad;

    /* If the contents of 'struct spi_ioc_transfer' ever change
     * incompatibly, then the ioctl number (currently 0) must change;
     * ioctls with constant size fields get a bit more in the way of
     * error checking than ones (like this) where that field varies.
     *
     * NOTE: struct layout is the same in 64bit and 32bit userspace.
     */
};

/* not all platforms use <asm-generic/ioctl.h> or _IOC_TYPECHECK() ... */
#define SPI_MSGSIZE(N) \
    ((((N)*(sizeof (struct spi_ioc_transfer))) < (1 << _IOC_SIZEBITS)) \
        ? ((N)*(sizeof (struct spi_ioc_transfer))) : 0)
#define SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(N) _IOW(SPI_IOC_MAGIC, 0, char[SPI_MSGSIZE(N)])


/* Read / Write of SPI mode (SPI_MODE_0..SPI_MODE_3) (limited to 8 bits) */
#define SPI_IOC_RD_MODE         _IOR(SPI_IOC_MAGIC, 1, __u8)
#define SPI_IOC_WR_MODE         _IOW(SPI_IOC_MAGIC, 1, __u8)

/* Read / Write SPI bit justification */
#define SPI_IOC_RD_LSB_FIRST        _IOR(SPI_IOC_MAGIC, 2, __u8)
#define SPI_IOC_WR_LSB_FIRST        _IOW(SPI_IOC_MAGIC, 2, __u8)

/* Read / Write SPI device word length (1..N) */
#define SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD    _IOR(SPI_IOC_MAGIC, 3, __u8)
#define SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD    _IOW(SPI_IOC_MAGIC, 3, __u8)

/* Read / Write SPI device default max speed hz */
#define SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ     _IOR(SPI_IOC_MAGIC, 4, __u32)
#define SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ     _IOW(SPI_IOC_MAGIC, 4, __u32)

/* Read / Write of the SPI mode field */
#define SPI_IOC_RD_MODE32       _IOR(SPI_IOC_MAGIC, 5, __u32)
#define SPI_IOC_WR_MODE32       _IOW(SPI_IOC_MAGIC, 5, __u32)



#endif /* SPIDEV_H */
```

`spi.h`:

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0+ WITH Linux-syscall-note */
#ifndef _UAPI_SPI_H
#define _UAPI_SPI_H

#include <linux/const.h>

#define SPI_CPHA        _BITUL(0)   /* clock phase */
#define SPI_CPOL        _BITUL(1)   /* clock polarity */

#define SPI_MODE_0      (0|0)       /* (original MicroWire) */
#define SPI_MODE_1      (0|SPI_CPHA)
#define SPI_MODE_2      (SPI_CPOL|0)
#define SPI_MODE_3      (SPI_CPOL|SPI_CPHA)
#define SPI_MODE_X_MASK     (SPI_CPOL|SPI_CPHA)

#define SPI_CS_HIGH     _BITUL(2)   /* chipselect active high? */
#define SPI_LSB_FIRST       _BITUL(3)   /* per-word bits-on-wire */
#define SPI_3WIRE       _BITUL(4)   /* SI/SO signals shared */
#define SPI_LOOP        _BITUL(5)   /* loopback mode */
#define SPI_NO_CS       _BITUL(6)   /* 1 dev/bus, no chipselect */
#define SPI_READY       _BITUL(7)   /* slave pulls low to pause */
#define SPI_TX_DUAL     _BITUL(8)   /* transmit with 2 wires */
#define SPI_TX_QUAD     _BITUL(9)   /* transmit with 4 wires */
#define SPI_RX_DUAL     _BITUL(10)  /* receive with 2 wires */
#define SPI_RX_QUAD     _BITUL(11)  /* receive with 4 wires */
#define SPI_CS_WORD     _BITUL(12)  /* toggle cs after each word */
#define SPI_TX_OCTAL        _BITUL(13)  /* transmit with 8 wires */
#define SPI_RX_OCTAL        _BITUL(14)  /* receive with 8 wires */
#define SPI_3WIRE_HIZ       _BITUL(15)  /* high impedance turnaround */
#define SPI_RX_CPHA_FLIP    _BITUL(16)  /* flip CPHA on Rx only xfer */

/*
 * All the bits defined above should be covered by SPI_MODE_USER_MASK.
 * The SPI_MODE_USER_MASK has the SPI_MODE_KERNEL_MASK counterpart in
 * 'include/linux/spi/spi.h'. The bits defined here are from bit 0 upwards
 * while in SPI_MODE_KERNEL_MASK they are from the other end downwards.
 * These bits must not overlap. A static assert check should make sure of that.
 * If adding extra bits, make sure to increase the bit index below as well.
 */
#define SPI_MODE_USER_MASK  (_BITUL(17) - 1)

#endif /* _UAPI_SPI_H */
```

What is the problem? Is there a problem with the application layer code or with the driver? What is the direction for troubleshooting?

Comment: Did you compile it?  Look at the source. https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/tools/spi/spidev_test.c?h=v6.6.18  The device can exist, but it does not support access or the ioctl. Do you have permission to use it?  If you are building it, then add some debug.  It is best to build it direct from the Linux tree.  You may have built it with PC ioctl numbering or something.

Comment: @artlessnoise It must have been compiled and there were no errors. The compilation result also added executable permissions and executed as `root`.

Comment: It can happen if the device tree and clocking is inappropriate.  For example on imx8x, there spi0 has a clocking issue with some older kernel version (but the message is different).  The ioctl() `SPI_IOC_WR_MODE32` is failing.  Try to change the mode settings.  Your SPI driver may not support the default for some reason.  Options, l, H, O, L, C, 3, Z, F, M, N, R, 2, 4, 8 will affect the mode bit.  You might want to print the mode if you are compiling.